# Picking up environment variables that have been set in docker compose file, from inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a postgres service in a docker compose file.
However, this service is not based directly on the postgres image. It is based on a dockerfile that builds on the postgres image.

This service in docker compose takes in the usual environment keys like POSTGRES_USER, etc

```yml
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${MYUSER}
```

I want to use POSTGRES_USER in an init script written to `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` via a heredoc. It doesn't work. eg:

```yaml
#  near top of docker file
ARG MYDB

...

# later on in file
COPY <<EOF /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$MYDB" <<-EOSQL
  ...
EOSQL
EOF
```

When the container runs, I see it had no value for `POSTGRES_USER`, but it does have a value for `MYDB` as i used `ARG MYDB`.

I don't see how I can set an equivalent `ENV POSTGRES_USER`, it seems to require a value to be provided in vscode, but this is already done in the compose file?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the file gets fully evaluated a the time BuildKit reads the `COPY` instruction.

At that point, your variable has no value a'd thus gets expanded to ``, instead of leaving an unexpanded `$POSTGRES_USER`.

From what you've shown, I don't see the point of taking the database name as a build time argument; just initialize the database as needed in the entrypoint without semi-hardcoding its name.

Otherwise just escape variables you don't want expanded in the file.

Comment: You answer is unclear. _At that point, your variable has no value_ : so when does it have a value? How is the underlying pg image able to make sense of it in order to create a superuser for the db? _Without semi-hardcoding its name_ : what? I'm trying to not hardcode the name at all.

Comment: Actually, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/get-environment-variable-value-in-dockerfile) explains that basically ARG is build time and ENV is runtime (passed to container) so my entire question betrays a misunderstanding of this. I'll just use ARGs throughout.